# Why are articles in Atlantic magazine difficult to comprehend for an average reader?

Tags: comprehension

I read articles on ny times, economist, atlantic etc. One thing I noticed is that articles on Atlantic are difficult to comprehend - I have to pay more attention or some times go back and re-read sentences.

What is that that makes these articles difficult to comprehend for an average reader? Formation of sentences? For what it is worth, I have no problem with the vocabulary used in all these sources.

Here is an [example](http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2013/06/when-men-lost-their-charm/309303/) I'm not saying every sentence that I read in this source difficult to comprehend. It is relatively harder to read compared to ny times, new yorker, economic etc

Comment: Can you quote any instance or example? We may be able to help you better that way.

Comment: This isn't really an English usage question, and as written relies on people answering being familiar with the magazine in question. Needs further information.

Comment: The inherent problem with your question is that unless we master the technology to become you for a day, it's almost impossible for us to accurately identify what it is about the articles you're finding difficult to comprehend. There are many things I could hazard a guess at, but EL&U isn't really intended for guesswork.

Comment: Where is your proof that your average reader finds Atlantic difficult to comprehend but not the NY Times, The New Yorker, or The Economist? Presumably, being a native speaker, you tend to veer toward the same publications and websites with which you are most familiar. Perhaps you write, or are used to a style of writing that the Atlantic does not share. In order to answer this question, a user should be well versed in several N. American magazines,  know the styles of several respected journalists before they can give any explanation. It seems a bit of a tall order to me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You are right - I should have worded the question as what is the difference between the writing style of Atlantic and ny times. Please add an answer if you are able to identify the differences. I'm not an english expert, so it hard for me to say differences in writing style.

Comment: @JohnClifford I might have worded the question poorly. But if it helps, I was trying get answers in terms of what Fumble Fingers is suggesting. You don't have to become me to answer the question ;)

Comment: Unfortunately being a Scot I'm unfamiliar with pretty much every NA publication so I wouldn't have been able to help much either way. :P

Comment: @Rathony I'm writing it from my phone, so the auto correct seems to be messing it up.. Nothing intentional. If I don't capitalize words you assume I can't comprehend articles from the Economist??

Comment: This seems to be getting off topic, so here is my last reply. I understand articles from the Atlantic - I have to pay extra attention however (relative to when I read from other common sources). I don't have anything against Atlantic or for Economist. I SIMPLY wanted to know what the differences in the writing styles. My english skills are average so thought someone here might be able to answer my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's effectively a "literary device". OP's linked article deliberately uses long sentences, convoluted syntax, and a slightly "upmarket" vocabulary to enhance the general sense of it being a "long-established, traditional, authoritative" publication (which *The Atlantic* is, I understand).

True, the style demands *slightly* more attention from the target readership - but in return those readers get a little fillip from knowing they're members of a somewhat exclusive "gentleman's club".

Obviously the flip side is that a few *potential* readers will be put off because they find the style to be just too much hard work. But as a rule, such people won't be the target readership anyway (because they're probably not part of the cultural / literary elite, so to speak).

---

In short, it's a little bit like an exclusive club with very high prices, or restaurant where the menu is entirely written in French (which keeps the riff-raff out without deterring the target customer base). Of course, exactly the same device can be used at the *opposite* end of the scale (exaggerated use of "street slang" can be used to reflect internal unity while keeping "mainstream society" at bay).

Comment: Thanks, you seem to understand what my question is about!! Could you explain more about the "convoluted syntax" part? That was the main intention of my question.

Comment: Well, glancing again at the text, I note this particular subheading written in bold text: *The dearth of charming American leading men seems acute, but only for a brief cultural moment did American movies elevate male charm.* Okay, that ones's not a *particularly* long sentence - but *dearth, acute, elevate* are all a bit "upmarket" compared to, say, *lack, serious, raise*. And syntactically, the ***but**-clause* is something of an inversion. Compare *Only for a few years were we married* with *We were only married for a few years* to see the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick list:

subjunctive **were** without **if**

parenthetic phrases interrupting the flow of the sentence

French (noir, politesse, civilité, jejune ,  insouciance)

phrases like "bruised suavity" (I thought "bruiser?")

archaism: perforce

recondite meanings:  declension

very odd mix in the name-dropping: Elizabeth Montagu, Madame Geoffrin, Viscountess Melbourne, Countess Greffulhe; Sonny Jurgensen, John McEnroe, Jim McMahon, Arnold Palmer

ornate periphrasis: hold charm in vague suspicion

mixing of registers: a proclivity to dish

use of argot: rent boy

Nothing like this in The Economist. Some overlap with The New Yorker.

Comment: I like that you've come at this question from the opposite direction (Me: ***Why do they** write in an opaque style?* You: ***What features** make the style opaque?*). Taking particular note of the exact question text, and OP's comment under my answer (made *before* you posted yours), I won't feel hard done by if OP switches his "Accept" vote to yours. (But I still think I made a useful point! :)